# Computer either black screens mid-usage or fails to post completely

Tags: boot, power-supply, hardware-failure, crash, reboot

So I've had my computer for almost a year now, and it has worked flawlessly sans a few problems with my Motherboard battery, but that was an easy fix by simply replacing it.

Just recently, in fact two days ago, my computer has started to do abnormal things. It started when playing intensive games such as Elite Dangerous trying to render a few million/billion stars in a map screen, and quickly flipping back to the main game, or playing an unoptimised game that upon inspection, uses 100% of my GPU and 60-90% CPU at all times. I would be playing, and then suddenly, the computer would black screen completely, (screen not lit-up, the actual HDMI input is recieving nothing, so the screen is off), then after a second or two my headset would die, and my input obviously doesn't function either.

I've opened the computer up about 6 times now, and taken everything out and put back in each time. My CPU has not a single bent pin, my GPU I *know* is fine, I don't know about the RAM (did a memory test but didn't know how to get the logs).

Now, it either posts and does the above, even when **not** in-game, or simply doesnt post at all. It just hangs, the BIOS screen doesn't even show to say its starting, the HDMI doesn't actually receive any input to begin with!

This has lead me and my close friends ***all*** to think its the PSU that is at fault. My computers specs are below, but upon recent inspection of the PSU specifications, it looks like it's severely under-amped on the 12V rail, and I think now I have made a mistake in buying it, only being 500W. Because of this, I have just yesterday purchased a Corsair VS650 which I'm going to install and see what happens when it arrives.

As for now, I want a professional opinion, as to what the problem may be, and how I can diagnose it. I actually looked in the "Event Viewer" and see that in the past 24 hours I've had 8 or so "CRITICAL" errors, which are (every single one of them) a 'Kernal Power' error. Another reason why I think its the PSU. Any ideas?

**Edit:**
There was a strange thing yesterday, that when I turned it on at one point it seemed to work, yet when I plugged in my Wireless Internet USB, it crashed immediately.

Also going to add, I've stuck a screwdriver on the JBAT1 pins on the Motherboard, which my manual says to do to reset the CMOS, and upon turning the computer on, the BIOS displayed, it worked for a while, however upon entering a game again, it broke once more.

**Computer specs:**

- CPU: Intel i5 6500
- GPU: GIGABYTE GTX960 4GB Overclocked(able)
- Motherboard: MSI H110M Gaming
- RAM: 2x4GB Crucial DDR4
- **PSU: Thermaltake 500W ATX OEM PSU**
- Storage: I've got a Samsung 128GB EVO for my OS and an extra 1TB WD HDD for my files.
- OS: Whatever the latest iteration of Windows 10 currently is.

Comment: certainty does sound like a power supply issue. Kind of odd that it occasionally won't post though... You could try checking the voltage discrepancies in BIOS. Might be a voltage issue instead of an amperage issue. That would seem more likely too given it's a recent development. On the other hand, ram can cause incredibly weird issues, which could fit  your description too. Try running memtest off a USB, and let it go for 5 or so passes.

Comment: @Blaine Thanks for trying to help! I'll download a memtest utility now. (The one I used was just the Windows Memory Diagnostic). As for voltage discrepancies, what voltages am I looking for? I've got no idea sadly :3

Comment: memtest86 is the standard utility for testing ram: http://www.memtest86.com/download.htm.     As for voltages, go into your bios, find something that says system monitor or monitoring, and go to voltages. It'll show you the expected voltage and the real voltage. (Eg: 12V: 12.32V). If the actual reading is within 0.5Vish of the expected reading, you're fine.

Comment: @Blaine Yep downloading it now. My System/12V Voltage reading is 11.712V and my System/5V Voltage is 5.160V so looks good there.

Comment: Alright. If ram is fine, then your diagnosis might be right! Just weird to me that it would suddenly start doing this after a year

Comment: @Blaine While I'm waiting on memtest, both me and my friend have a single wall-socket, which I run a powerboard, and him 4 (terrible isn't it?) from the single socket. His has worked fine for years with no problem, but is there a possibility that the sharing from one socket could be an issue?

Comment: sharing from one socket isn't an issue. If it was, you'd know because your circuit breaker would throw and nothing would work. Another thought occored to me. Do you have integrated graphics? You could try running off it for a time and see if the problem still happens. If not, then something may in fact be wrong with your graphics card. Just a thought since you didn't specify how you know it's working

Comment: @Blaine I've run GPU tests when the PC wasn't breaking, and it was running full-throttle perfectly fine and have assumed it perfectly fine. The CPU *does* infact have onboard-graphics, however when I attempted to run the HDMI straight from it, the same issue persisted.

Comment: Ok, nice. When you tested this, was your graphics card still installed? If it was installed, computer might still be using some of it's resources. Make sure the computer is configured to use integrated graphics and remove the graphics card. Kind of a stretch, but it could still be the issue.

Comment: @Blaine Woops! Looks like I've been skipping ahead. Adding it to the list to-do! :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61908/discussion-between-blaine-and-finnrayment).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so Finnrayment and I started a chat in which we determined:

1. The computer often doesn't post, and at this point, often crashes at the login screen, or shortly after.
2. Memtest86 completes one pass without any issues
3. (most importantly) The computer works fine if you take out the graphics card and use the integrated graphics.

We then ran a cpu stress test. This means that without the graphics card but with cpu on max, the system should be using more power than with the graphics card at idle (still on the 12V line). Since it still did not crash, this means that the problem was most likely NOT the power supply.

The only remaining candidate is the GPU. Could be a problem with the graphics card's vram, but exactly the problem is as of now still unknown. However, since it was narrowed down the the GPU, and it's still in warrenty, he can RMA it and should be left with a working system :)

**Edit: So he got a new power supply and tested that, and for SOME reason, it works with the gpu, with the new power supply. So it looks like the problem was the *PSU* all along**

Comment: Well hey, lets not rule out that the CPU only uses (on average) 65 watts whereas the GPU requires 400. Still hoping on that PSU but it's not looking too good.

Comment: good point. But then again, 65 watts is much more than idle cpu (1-10 watts) plus idle gpu (10-15 watts).

Comment: YES!!!! Oh my god Blaine! So I got the PSU today, installed it and it had some stupid CPU-VRAM detection issue. Being tempremental as it was, I got it working WITH GPU and did the Furmark benchmarks for 720p and 1080p perfectly fine! I can't thank you enough for the help you gave me. I'll have to get back to you if anything else goes wrong (touchwood) but at the moment it looks perfect!

Comment: WHAAAAAAT, NO WAY!!! That's awesome and makes no sense simultaneously! Haha, sorry for steering you in the wrong direction then, but kudos to you and your friends for having the right answer all along :D

Comment: Hahaha! No way did you steer me wrongly. You cut down all the available options to a GPU and a PSU. I couldn't of done it without you!